# How to enable echo service for tcp or udp on well-known port 7 on Mac OS X 10.8 or above?

Tags: macos, network, tcp

I am learning TCP/IP protocol with a Mac, and need echo service (refer to [RFC 862], or [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol)) to test network. But it seems to OS X doesn't implement it or disable it.

I learned that launchd replaced inetd, you can create a launchd Property List File to launch daemons. In that way you can control some network service. So i edited telnet.plist (located in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons), set "Disabled" to "NO", and successfully enable telnet service. But I don't find echo.plist or something similar.

Or, I can create an echo.plist according to telnet.plist
[image]

But what ProgramArguments should be? Is there a built-in daemon for echo service of which name maybe echod?

Or, I have to compile inetd from source?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the echo service isn't implemented in OS X. You may use either a [Java echo client/server](http://alexander-hill.tumblr.com/post/79482280804/how-to-write-an-echo-server-and-client-with-javas) or [CocoaEcho](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaEcho/CocoaEcho.zip) instead.

After unzipping the file check the folder *.../build/Debug*. I tested CocoaEcho server/client in 10.9.5 and it still works though it was built for 10.7. If you use a newer OS X version you may have to recompile it.

Comment: Does it support both tcp and udp, and can I set CocoaEcho's port  to be constant to port 7 and assign the port with name "echo", as the original echo service should be. I known it may be unnecessary to do, just want to know how to do it.

Comment: @kinishinai CocoaEcho is just sample code. Starting it, a port in the dynamic range (49152 - 65535) will be assigned. But if you are a programmer you may change the source to use port 7 and recompile it.